# Wordpress csv import duplicate

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, csv

I've used an adapted version of a csv import plugin for wordpress. It imports the csv to create and update posts. To update existing posts I've added an edit that finds the post id by title, then if it exists it overwrites, otherwise it creates a new post.

Problem is that it seems to not be very reliable! If I import the same csv several times it over-writes most of them but I get a few duplicates. Is there any way I can make this more reliable, or is there another way I can deal with duplicate posts?

main function for creating posts here

```
 function create_post($data, $options) {
    extract($options);
//edit 1 added here
   global $wpdb;  
//end

    $data = array_merge($this->defaults, $data);
    $type = $data['csv_post_type'] ? $data['csv_post_type'] : 'post';
    $valid_type = (function_exists('post_type_exists') &&
        post_type_exists($type)) || in_array($type, array('post', 'page'));

    if (!$valid_type) {
        $this->log['error']["type-{$type}"] = sprintf(
            'Unknown post type "%s".', $type);
    }

    $new_post = array(
        'post_title'   => convert_chars($data['csv_post_title']),
        'post_content' => wpautop(convert_chars($data['csv_post_post'])),
        'post_status'  => $opt_draft,
        'post_type'    => $type,
        'post_date'    => $this->parse_date($data['csv_post_date']),
        'post_excerpt' => convert_chars($data['csv_post_excerpt']),
        'post_name'    => $data['csv_post_slug'],
        'post_author'  => $this->get_auth_id($data['csv_post_author']),
        'tax_input'    => $this->get_taxonomies($data),
        'post_parent'  => $data['csv_post_parent'],
    );

// edit 2 here
    $new_post['ID'] = $wpdb->get_var( "SELECT ID FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_title = '" .   $data['csv_post_title'] . "'" );
// ends

    // pages don't have tags or categories
    if ('page' !== $type) {
        $new_post['tags_input'] = $data['csv_post_tags'];

        // Setup categories before inserting 
        $cats = $this->create_or_get_categories($data, $opt_cat);
        $new_post['post_category'] = $cats['post'];
    }

// edit 3
    if(!empty($new_post['ID'])) {
    $id = wp_update_post($new_post);
} else {
    $id = wp_insert_post($new_post);
}
// ends

    if ('page' !== $type && !$id) {
        // cleanup new categories on failure
        foreach ($cats['cleanup'] as $c) {
            wp_delete_term($c, 'category');
        }
    }
    return $id;
}
```

thanks

Comment: In my plugin CSV 2 POST I refer to this has post adoption. I recommend comparison on the post_name/permalink where possible unless you know your data well. The title (post_title) can have duplicate values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed! I used the built in wordpress function, `get_page_by_title` . Here is the code I used to target the correct post.

```
if (!get_page_by_title( $bpp_title, 'OBJECT', 'publications')) {


    $id = wp_insert_post($new_post);

    } else {

        $bpp_page = get_page_by_title( $bpp_title, 'OBJECT', 'publications');
        $new_post['ID'] = $bpp_page->ID;

        $id = wp_update_post($new_post);

    }
```